# jquery CPU Usage 25 / 25

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a vldpersonals dating site I paid a developer to make the way of updating messages automatically before people will have to refresh the page to read he put this code in the footer  jquery now eat too much process    this code

```
function downloadJSAtOnload() {
  var element = document.createElement("script");
  element.src = "includes/js/defer.js";
  document.body.appendChild(element);
}

if (window.addEventListener)
  window.addEventListener("load", downloadJSAtOnload, false);
else if (window.attachEvent)
  window.attachEvent("onload", downloadJSAtOnload);
else window.onload = downloadJSAtOnload;

jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  var $scores = $("#headernav");
  setInterval(function () {
    $scores.load("index.php #headernav");
  }, 7000);
});
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: If you paid a developer to build something, perhaps get them to look at it? Also from the code you've pasted, nothing should be particularly process heavy.

Comment: the site has become heavy and the processes are 25 to 25 and 500 error what do I do because I'm new and I do not speak English well

Comment: Sounds like something going wrong server-side, however what you've posted is client side code so can't be causing this problem. I suggest you get back in contact with the developer who built this for you. Short of you posting your entire source code here (Please do **not** do that) there's not really anything we can do to help in this situation since we have no visibility of the problem.